# How to provide folder location in logstash config file as input

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Below is my sample logstash conf  file.

```
input{
    file{
        path => "D:\Log\apacheTest.log" \\here i want to give path for the folder
        start_position => beginning

    }
}
```

I tried by give path up to folder but it does not parse the files that are being added in to that folder,also tried by use of .* pattern in path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
input{
    file{
        path => "D:/Log/*.*"
        start_position => beginning

    }
}
```

Comment: With forward slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: Nice! If you want to use backslashes you need to escape it like this `\\ ` but there has been reports that in certain versions of logstash globbing (i.e. `*.*`) didn't work with backslashes.